# TPU-VM gives access denied when accessing Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu, google-bucket

I have a number of Google cloud TPU-VMs which need to write to a Bucket.

Most of them work fine, but the one I created this morning is giving me Access Denied when I run `gsutil -m cp test_file.txt gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME`:

```
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access denied.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Access denied.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
```

The VM is identical to all the others as far as I can see (same project, same versions, same region, same service account, `gcloud config list` and `gcloud auth list` give identical results) - any ideas why it's behaving differently?

This still happens even when I give `allUsers` public permissions to write to the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the scope of the machine ([link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes))? It sounds like your machine has `read-only` scope instead of `read_write`.

How to verify:

- Go to the console, and select your TPU
- In the `DETAILS` tab, click `Equivalent REST`
- Check the `scope` under `serviceAccount`, and make sure you have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`

It likely happens when you create a TPU via GCP console as the default scope is read-only. But creating the machine with gCloud CLI won't cause this problem.